# How to synchronize movement between multiple QT graphics view widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am trying to build a tool that can compare images side-by-side.  To do this, I have used three graphics view widgets in QT.  They all zoom at the same rate, but I cannot seem to find anything online about how to link the movement of the images (aka - the drag and drop with the mouse).  Is this feature even possible to construct?

Here is what the GUI looks like:

Image compare GUI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, every time I used a QGraphicsView, I ended up subclassing it cause it didn't provide everything I needed "as public".

In your case though, I believe this is as simple as doing:

```
connect(graphicsView1->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        graphicsView2->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(graphicsView2->verticalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        graphicsView1->verticalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

If you prefer, call some slots to perform more than a 1-to-1 action:

```
void MyClass::scrollGraphicsView1(int value)
{
    graphicsView1->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value);
}
void MyClass::scrollGraphicsView2(int value)
{
    graphicsView2->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value);
}
```